# Scala case class to convert to jsonObject

Tags: json, scala, class, case

I have a case class object, and I want to convert this object to `JsonObject` (not `JsonString`) using (`com.fasterxml.jackson` which is Java API)
but the output I got is `{}`, which is not expected.

How I solved is :

I wrote a Scala Pojo class (How we write in Java with getter and setter, may be not correct way to write Pojo in Scala, as my knowledge in Scala is very minimal.) which solved the problem, and got proper `jsonObject`.

Do any one of you know better solution other than this?

Comment: Where does `JsonObject` come from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Play framework, then have a look here:

- http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/
- http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/